# Date import from CSV to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, date, import, wizard

I'm trying to import csv file containing data to my SQL server using SQL server import wizard in Microsoft SQL server management studio.

CSV file date looks like this:

```
02-04-2021
03-04-2021
05-04-2021
06-04-2021
07-04-2021
08-04-2021
09-04-2021
10-04-2021
12-04-2021
13-04-2021
14-04-2021
15-04-2021
16-04-2021
17-04-2021
19-04-2021
20-04-2021
21-04-2021
22-04-2021
23-04-2021
24-04-2021
26-04-2021
27-04-2021
28-04-2021
29-04-2021
30-04-2021
```

In the wizard I chose source DataType as date, and destination table has datatype date (i tried also datetime, datetime2, all the same trouble)
Imported completed successfully, but the result is:

```
2021-01-04
2021-02-04
2021-03-04
2021-05-04
2021-06-04
2021-07-04
2021-08-04
2021-09-04
2021-10-04
2021-12-04
2021-04-13
2021-04-14
2021-04-15
2021-04-16
2021-04-17
2021-04-19
2021-04-20
2021-04-21
2021-04-22
2021-04-23
2021-04-24
2021-04-26
2021-04-27
2021-04-28
2021-04-29
2021-04-30
```

As you can see, days and months mixed, date is wrong. Some rows are correct, but in some rows there is a month instead of day.

What can I do?

Comment: The format you have, which appears to be `dd-MM-yyyy` is ambiguous, I'm surprised you didn't actually get conversion errors. You would need to either ensure you that the import process runs where the `DATEFORMAT` or `LANGUAGE` setting has been set to one that uses `dmy` formats, or you could import the data into a staging table and then `INSERT` the data into your production table using an explicit `CONVERT` with a style code.

Comment: The import wizard has a *Locale* option - did you set this correctly?

Comment: It actually appears that the import worked correctly.  The display in SSMS is showing the date as YYYY-MM-DD.  The date/time data types are not stored in a text format - the client (in this case SSMS) converts the internal format to the external YYYY-MM-DD for display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do via T-SQL in SSMS.

As @Lamu pointed out, input file date format is ambiguous. So the following line specifies it exactly:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
```

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl 
(
   inputDate      DATE
);

-- to let know format of the date in the *.csv file
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

BULK INSERT dbo.tbl 
FROM 'e:\temp\Faenno.csv'
WITH  
(
   DATAFILETYPE    = 'char', --widechar',
   FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
   ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
   CODEPAGE = '65001'
);

SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl;
```